# 'Subquery returned more than 1 value' when updating a table that has a trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-trigger

I want to update 2 or more rows in a table with the same value:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[forms]
   SET [forExport] = 0

 WHERE (id = 4497 or id = 4496)
```

But I get back this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Do you have a trigger on this table?

Comment: Check your `forms` table for a trigger.  It sounds like you have one that's expecting there to only ever be one record updated at a time.

Comment: Yes... which logs the changed cells

Comment: Ding ding...the trigger is the problem. Post the trigger code and we can help.

Comment: @aggicd . . . Your trigger is broken.  It would be nice is SQL Server specified that in the error message.

Comment: Ok thank you. I just needed to know if that was the problem. No need to alter the trigger yet

Comment: @aggicd Your trigger cause the error, you should use joins.

Comment: @aggicd You really should consider altering it anyway.  You'll get this same issue if you ever update more than one record at a time on this table (which is not an unreasonable request).

Comment: On the contrary, you do need to fix that trigger. Any trigger that assumes only 1 row being updated is a ticking timebomb. I have a buddy who did some consulting for a company that literally had to close their doors because all of their triggers were like this and the cost to fix them all was too much.

Comment: @SeanLange True, that what I mean by _use joins_